# Cypher: what parts of a pattern can be bound to a variable?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I can get all `User` nodes like this:

```
MATCH (n:User)
RETURN n
```

In this case, `n` is bound to the node. But let's say I want to write a Cypher query which gets the `name` property of every node with the label `User` and a property with the key `name`, and return this as `username`. I write:

```
MATCH (n:User { name: username })
RETURN username
```

But this appears to not be possible: the Cypher parser does not accept the identifier `username` in that location of the pattern. Is there another way to do it? What positions of a pattern is it possible to put an identifier? Just nodes and relationships?

(Yes, I'm aware I can bind to the node, check whether a `name` property exists, and if so extract that value. But it would be more elegant to directly pattern match on the property.)

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding. So the question is can you test for the presence of and pattern match on a property and bind a new variable at the same time (slight analog of a match group in regex)? No is the answer, as you say only Nodes and Relationships.

Comment: @JohnMark13 thanks very much. If you write this out as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Maybe hold off, someone has down voted me, maybe there is a way to do it (almost certain there isn't).

Comment: Can you clarify? From your description, it seems as if you simply want to return the `name` property with the alias `username`. You would just use the `WITH` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question posed in the title:

Within the `MATCH` clause specifically, paths, nodes, and relationships can be bound to identifiers:

```
MATCH p = (n)-[r]-(m)
```

After the `MATCH` clause, in combination with the `WITH` clause, anything can be bound to an identifier:

```
MATCH p = (n)-[r]-(m)
WITH n.name AS identifier
```

or

```
MATCH p = (n)-[r]-(m)
WITH COUNT(r) AS some_identifier
```

or

```
MATCH p = (n)-[r]-(m)
WITH EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | x.name) AS another_identifier
```

etc.

Use `WITH` if you want to bind anything other than a path, node, or relationship to an identifier. Your specific example seems to showcase a misunderstanding of the role of the curly braces within a `MATCH` clause. They are there for what I like to call "shorthand `WHERE` conditioning." The curly braces allow you to condition on node and relationship properties within the `MATCH` clause instead of conditioning in a subsequent `WHERE` clause.

```
MATCH (n:User {name:"Alice"})
RETURN n
```

and

```
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE n.name = "Alice"
RETURN n
```

are identical. It is a matter of convenience / preference.

TL;DR - No, you can't bind the `name` property to an identifier `username` within a `MATCH` clause. Use `WITH n.name AS username` to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily return properties of a node

```
MATCH (n:User)
RETURN n.name
```

you can access these properties in any expressions

```
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE n.name = "John"
RETURN n.name
```

if you want to assign this property to an indentifier you can do it with `WITH`

```
MATCH (n:User)
WITH n.name as userName   
RETURN userName
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is very different to my answer and still represents a "no" to binding within the Match expression?

Comment: @JohnMark13 The curly braces within the parentheses is a shorthand for `WHERE` conditioning. It's not meant for binding to an identifier.

Comment: @JohnMark13 Ah, you said that at the end of your answer. Should have read all the way through. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit - Actual Answer**
With regards to binding a variable to the matched properties this is not possible. Like you say the binding is only applicable to Nodes and Relationships. You can also name values in `Return` statements and in `With` clauses.

It is important to note that the values in parenthesis are used to select nodes (like a WHERE clause) but only work on exact matches. I'm not sure if there is any roadmap item for allowing pattern matching inside the parenthesis, making this valid:

```
MATCH (n:User{name:"Jam.*"})
RETURN n
```

In previous iterations of Neo (and you still can if you wish) you could use the START semantics to do index matches based on a Lucene Index, but that too would not have allowed property binding.

Still you do not need to test for the presence of the property as a missing property will not match anyway. As you correctly surmised your only option is:

```
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE n.name =~ "James.*"
RETURN n.name AS username
```

Or for non regex:

```
MATCH (n:User{name:"James"})
RETURN n.name AS username
```

**Original Answer**
Of course, if you want to match all users and return a list of values.

```
MATCH (n:User)
RETURN n.name AS username
```

Or a single value which contains an array of usernames:

```
MATCH (n:User)
RETURN COLLECT(n.name) AS usernames
```

Or if you want to match a specific user:

```
MATCH (n:User{propToMatch:"valToMatch"})
RETURN n.name AS username
```

Values in the MATCH in parenthesis are used like a WHERE clause and not as the return value.

Comment: So the answer is no, I can't bind an identifier to a property value in a pattern?

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I didn't understand that from the question. As far as I am aware you cannot do what you asked, no.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to bind a property value to an identifier in a pattern. The only things that can be bound to identifiers in a pattern are nodes and relationships.

The only way to achieve the same query is to manually check for the existence of the property key on the node and extract the property value if the key exists, like this:

```
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE HAS (n.name)
RETURN n.name AS username
```